# Bash: ensuring a variable is set without erasing any existing value

Tags: bash

Let's say I'm running a bash script under `set -u`.  Obviously, for any given variable, I need to ensure that it's set.  Something like:

```
foo=
```

However, if I want to keep any pre-existing value that might be set by my caller, this would overwrite it.  A simple solution to this problem is to do this instead:

```
: ${foo:=}
```

But I have some code that does it this (more complicated) way:

```
foo=${foo+$foo}
```

Now, I *know* this second way works.  My question is, is there *any* advantage to it over the first way?  I am assuming there is but now can't remember what it was.  Can anyone either think of an edge case (no matter how obscure) where these two constructs would behave differently, or provide a compelling explanation that they can't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is, is there *any* advantage to it over the first way?

Maybe this is subjective, but one advantage is that it clearly *looks* like a variable assignment. Anyone who sees the command `foo=${foo+$foo}` will immediately understand that it sets the variable `foo` (even if they need to look up the `${parameter+word}` notation to figure out what it sets it to); but someone who sees the command `: ${foo:=}` is likely to completely miss that it has the side-effect of modifying `foo`. (The use of `:` is definitely a *hint* that something might be happening, since `:` itself does nothing; but it's not as blatant.)

And of course, someone searching the script for `foo=` will find the former but not the latter.

That said, I would personally write this as either `foo="${foo-}"` or `foo="${foo:-}"`, which still makes clear that it sets `foo`, but is a *bit* simpler than `foo=${foo+$foo}`. I also think that readers are more likely to be familiar with `${parameter-word}` than `${parameter+word}`, but I haven't asked around to check.

Comment: Your logic is sound.  I think I'll switch to your suggestion of `foo=${foo-}`.

Answer (score 3):

I can't think of any case where they would differ. They're just alternative logic for the same thing.

The meaning of the simple solution is: If `foo` is unset/empty, set it to the empty string.

The meaning of your code is: If `foo` is set, set it to itself, otherwise set it to an empty string.

Your code seems like more work -- why set something to itself? Just do nothing and it will keep its value. That's what the simpler version does.

You can also simplify the simple solution further by removing the `:` in the parameter expansion.

```
: ${foo=}
```

This makes it only test whether `foo` is unset. If it's set to the empty string, no default needs to be assigned.